# Error in uploading multiple images

Tags: php, image, file-upload, image-uploading

I am trying to upload multiple images at once here is what i've got so far:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

        $file_name=$_FILES["image"]["name"];

            foreach($file_name as $files)
            {
                $target_path = "Sub_uploads/".$files;

                if(move_uploaded_file($files["image"]["tmp_name"],$target_path)) 
                {   

                    $target_path="Sub_uploads/".$files;

                    $sql   = "INSERT INTO product_images (image) VALUES ('$target_path')"; 
                    $query = mysql_query($sql); 
                }
            }
             echo "<script>alert('data inserted');document.location='Sub_CateGory_image.php'</script>";
}
?>
```

It seems so that the error occurs at this line: `if(move_uploaded_file($files["image"]["tmp_name"],$target_path))`

Comment: Please specify the error reported.

Comment: Just replace $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"] with $files["image"]["tmp_name"]

Comment: i try this but it is not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you iterate over array of `name`, the connected `tmp_name` property will have the same key as current iterated `name`. So, add a `key` to your `foreach` and get a `tmp_name` under this key:

```
$file_name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
foreach($file_name as $key => $files)   // add `$key` here
{
    $target_path = "Sub_uploads/".$files;
    // use `$key` to get connected `tmp_name`
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$key], $target_path)) 
    {   
        $target_path="Sub_uploads/".$files;
        $sql   = "INSERT INTO product_images (image) VALUES ('$target_path')"; 
        $query = mysql_query($sql); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use variable of  `ForEach` `$files`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

        $file_name=$_FILES;

            foreach($file_name as $files)
            {
                $target_path = "Sub_uploads/".$files["image"]["name"];

                if(move_uploaded_file($files["image"]["tmp_name"],$target_path)) 
                {   

                    $target_path="Sub_uploads/".$files["image"]["name"];

                    $sql   = "INSERT INTO product_images (image) VALUES ('$target_path')"; 
                    $query = mysql_query($sql); 
                }
            }
             echo "<script>alert('data inserted');document.location='Sub_CateGory_image.php'</script>";
}
```

Comment: `$files` is a string.

Comment: Please, if you don't know the structure of `$_FILES` array - don't answer. Your edited answer is still __incorrect__.